# search diffrent tags and replace in a single preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode, phpbb3

I have this kind of retrieved record from a database where I want to decode formatting values and replace it with appropriate html tag so that it will work fine on display:

```
[size=150:3a9xfsiy][color=#000080:3a9xfsiy]hello world[/color:3a9xfsiy][/size:3a9xfsiy]
```

This record was created by phpBB and I am using it to display on other part of the website outside phpBB's control..

What ive tried is to use PREG_REPLACE but question is, is there any way to read different formatted tags as one in regex? example:

```
[size=150:3a9xfsiy] and [/size:3a9xfsiy] must be searched in a single preg_replace
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the BBCode code that comes with PHP?  http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
    $ret = 'I gave my Word to you Word.';
    $pattern = '/\bWord\b/i';
    $ret = preg_replace($pattern,"Heart",$ret);
    var_dump($ret);
?>
```

string(29) "I gave my Heart to you Heart."

Or if this is what suits you

You could just use str_replace:

```
$str = str_replace(array('<tag>', '</tag>'), array('<newtag>', '</newtag>', $str);
```

Comment: Just replace your tags in there

Comment: what if the value of $ret is: 
$ret = 'I gave my Word to you \Word.';

Can you still use only one preg_replace for both Word and \Word?

Answer (score 1):

Phpbb provides a function for this. [Generate_text_for_display](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Generate_text_for_display). When you retrieve it from db, include phpbb functions and apply this function.

Also you can use [this class](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/develop/phpBB/includes/bbcode.php).

Read more about [parsing text](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Tutorial.Parsing_text).

Comment: this is built in for phpBB right?
How can i use it if im going to use it outside phpBB?

Comment: Phpbb is open source. Just copy the files.